Extending Interface With generic base interface
I have a generic base type and want to extend it with different interfaces. How can I do?
interface ITypeBase<T> {
   loading: boolean;
   onSubmit: (filters: T) => void;
}

export default ITypeBase;

interface IMyFormType extends ITypeBase?{
   name: string;
   surname: string;
}


Do you just want to provide a concrete type for T? Or do you want to keep T generic in IMyFormType?

The first one, to provide a concrete type for T.

interface IMyFormType extends ITypeBase<SomeConcreteType> {}

Sorry for the confusion just need to send IMyFormType to the onSubmit event.  Something like interface IMyFormType extends ITypeBase<IMyFormType> {}

So then... why don't you write interface IMyFormType extends ITypeBase<IMyFormType>? It's valid syntax and it might even represent what you're trying to do (but that's not obvious from the question). If you've solved your own problem you can write up an answer post for it. It not, then please [edit] to clarify exactly what the problem is. As it stands this risks being closed as needing more details or clarity.
